# how to import data from google drive to google cloud automatically

Tags: mysql-workbench, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have a datawarehouse in google cloud and my data is in excel format at google drive i want to import the data from google drive to google cloud sql datawarehouse automatically . how can i do it please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a program that lists your Drive files and reads them using the Drive API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), and then writes them using one of the Google Cloud Storage APIs (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)